# at the top of one's lungs vs out of his lungs

Tags: grammar, idioms

> This time he came with her, his breath **screaming out of his lungs**,
> his body straining upward as he let go and finally emptied himself
> into her.

I heard "out of his lungs" isn't the same as at the top of one's lung. Is this the case or are both completely valid and mean the same thing?

Comment: In this case, ["screaming" means "fast"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/screaming), not "loud". "Screaming fast" is how quickly the air came out of his lungs. "Screaming at the top of his lungs" refers instead to the volume of the scream which may or may not be related to the speed of the air exiting his lungs.

Comment: "At the top of his lungs", meaning 'loudly', is a local American English idiom, practically never seen in British English.

Answer (score 1):

There are two somewhat similar English set-phrases involving screaming and lungs:

> "... scream [your/his/her] lungs out."

which implies screaming until you get too tired to scream any more; and

> "... scream at the top of [your/his/her] lungs."

which implies screaming as loudly as you can possibly scream.

In both cases the verb "scream" is basically a synonym for crying/yelling.

---

However, in your provided example, which states:

> "... his breath screaming out of his lungs..."

the word "scream" actually has a different meaning entirely.

In this case, "screaming out" is what "his breath" is doing, which means it is coming out fast/forcefully.  So, a better synonym for this context would be something like "whizzing out" or "rushing out" similar to how one might say:

> "The car came [screaming/rushing/whizzing] out of the alley and nearly hit a pedestrian!"